# How to use model and serializer in Python to connect to various databases using the mysql connector?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

I need to connect multiple instances (nearly 100). Is there a way to connect multiple instances of mysql connector python without using a cursor?

I already tried using cursor.
common Django methods?

```
     connection_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
                    pool_name=dbname,
                    pool_size=1,
                    pool_reset_session=True,
                    host=host,
                    database=dbname,
                    user=os.getenv("DYNAMIC_DB_USERNAME"),
                    password=os.getenv("DYNAMIC_DB_PASSWORD"),
                )
                connection_object = connection_pool.get_connection()
    with connection_object .cursor(buffered=True) as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""select * from employee""")

        row = dictfetchall(cursor)
```

I'll need to do the same thing with the model and serializer methods. Is it possible to rewrite in

Comment: Is your question about how to use multiple databases in django?

Comment: yes.Initially, I attempted to update the settings database. I'm having a problem where details from one instance appear in another. So I tried the method described above. It is fully operational. want to make use of serializers and models I'll need to do the same thing with the model and serializer methods. Is it possible to rewrite in common Django methods?

Comment: I don't know if I get your point or not, however, as per what I got, you can use multiple databases in Django.
you have to update the `DATABASES` objects in the `settings.py` file to contain a lot of databases connections,
then you have to automatically or manually select which database you want to read, update, add, and delete by using:
`Author.objects.using('default')`
when you want to perform any action you have to use:
`my_object.save(using='legacy_users')`
Ref.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: As of now we get database credentials through token. so couldn't set it in settings.py. Each connections we couldn't change the db details.